# How do I clear a blocked URL in email response

Tags: facebook, url, policy

Recently email responses to FB comments are refused by FB's servers with the following message:

The error that the other server returned was:
554 5.7.1 POL-P6 http://postmaster.facebook.com/response_codes?ip=209.85.223.172#pol-m Message refused

POL-P6 The message contains a url that has been blocked by Facebook.

Now, the only URL in the message is a link to my home page (for my tree farm)
http://sherwoods-forests.com.

Going over this policy page (at http://postmaster.facebook.com/response_codes?ip=209.85.210.175#pol-m ) I can find no place that will explain why this is occuring.

To verify it was this URL, I 're-replied' to a message, but edited the link out of my signature.  Sure enough that one went through without a problem.

In addition, I went and 'shared' this link on my status page to see if it was generally blocked.  No, it was not.  Had no problems.

I have searched through the web page for possible spam words -- and found nothing.

Q1.  Is there a way to find out why a URL is blocked by facebook?
Q2.  Is there a way to clear a blocked URL.

Comment: Try running the URL through the debugger here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Good idea.  And while it tells me more than I ever wanted to know, there is no indicator in the output that there is a problem with the url.

Comment: More grist:  If my signature link is

Comment: More grist:  If my signature link is

http://sherwoods-forest.com 

The mail bounces with an error.

If I add the following /  e.g. http://sherwoods-forests.com/ it still doesn't work.  Making it http://sherwoods-forests.com/Home/Home.html is accepted.  Go figure

Comment: Never mind.  It still borks.  Just takes longer.

Comment: I get this bounce message just by replying without any additional URLs. So, the only URLs the e-mail contains are Facebook ones that were in the original comment notification.

Comment: One first step is to report it to FB here:

http://www.facebook.com/help/326603310765065/

Comment: If you reply with a random "good" URL (google.com/wikipedia.com) (and removing the original message), do you still get the error?

Comment: You can also report it here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs I tried searching for pol-p6 there, but the bug report page seems to be a bit buggy. It claims to find 1 result, but doesn't display anything :| http://developers.facebook.com/bugs?search_view=search&&search_statuses[0]=open&search_texts[0]=pol-p6

Comment: I started having this problem a few weeks ago when replying from gmail.  I have no email signature.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue. So I used a url shortner like http://goo.gl/ instead of posting the exact link of the blocked url.

Facebook accepted  the shortened url of the page. After which facebook started to accept all emails containing the page url normally like before. There was no further use of url shortener.